# Get custom requests from Crashlythics

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I saw in the fabric crashlythics dashboard they use a lot of graphql, I was wondering if there was any documentation available to create your own overviews because sometimes it takes too much time to click everywhere. And I also want to show it on our internal Dashboard system.

Answer (score 1):

Todd from Fabric. We don't offer any APIs for programmatic access to your data at this time. That means it's not currently possible to show the data on your internal system. Thanks!